How to observe pubsub push window changing with failing requests?
I have a cloud run endpoint that gets triggered by a push type pubsub subscription and the cloudrun api is a composite api which does 2-3 operations and then it returns. I am observing at high load times few of the third party things like redis and firestore produce timeouts. In that case I am expecting pubsub will control the load (as per the document -> delivery rate) since there will be nacks coming from service. All the requests are getting successful in push backoffs but my service is experiencing the failures. Please help me what i am missing or how to monitor the push window?
I tried to reproduce the scenario where i was pushing 1000 messages to pubsub and my cloudrun instance was set to max 1 with 1 concurrency and 10secs timeout. I observed the send_request_count is increasing first then it settles but as per the slow start algorithm it should increase gradually based on the load handling capacity.
Attached the graph below.
Graph of send_request_count and unreachable requests
Blue line -> send_request_count
Red line ->. No of unreachable request

I didn't catch your issue and your question. Can you reformulate?

Okay let me rephrase this, Google Cloud PubSub subscription pushing messages to a Cloud Function at such a high rate despite a high error rate? According to this (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#delivery_rate) it should start with less number of push and after successful delivery it should increase the rate.

Did you configure your Subscription? Or did you deploy your cloud function mentioning only the topic and let the magic happen?

Yeah i have configured the subscription in the following way:
Delivery type: Push
Message retention duration: 7d
Expiry period: 31d
Ack deadline: 180s
Retry policy: Exponential backoff (min-80s, max-600s)

That's the correct configuration. You can open a case to Google Cloud Support to deep dive in your case.

Ok. Thanks you.
